# Qt program have no text and i haven't font error

Tags: windows, qt, cross-compiling, raspbian, raspberry-pi3

sorry if my english isn't perfect but my first language is french.

My problem is I have a cross-compiler on my window for raspbian and i finally did it, but when i execute the program on my pi the widget on window has no text and i don't have a close button. Someone gave me a code that works perfectly on his raspberry pi and i have the same result. With both codes it's the same result: just the basic window with a push button "test" written over it. So I know that my issue isn't my cross compiler but is on my pi. I tried to uninstall qt5-default package,reinstall it and upgrade all packages, but isn't effective. i tried to run linuxfb plugin with this command -./myprogram -platform linuxfb but i have the graphical bug... take a look at this picture.

[my program it's on the left corner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9sny.jpg)

I have also posted on [Qt forum](https://forum.qt.io/topic/76463/cross-compile-dont-gen-qlabel-and-qpushbutton-and-fontconfig-pre-condition/49), but the reply time is very slow. it'll have been three weeks that i tried to find the issue. if anyone can provide a solution or an idea for this problem i will take any suggestions.

Thanks for reading this message.

Kuba Ober gave me a solution to solved it take a another microsd reinstall a raspbian img with qt5 and it's work!!! but what is exactly the issue i don't know but this solution work.

Comment: did you try that ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18518280/raspberry-pi-qt5-set-physical-screen-size

Comment: no I don't try that and it's don't seems my problem, nut I will try that tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I know that my issue isn't my cross compiler but is on my pi

That's unlikely - it's easy to check: download a fresh Raspbian image to an SD card, boot it up, and try your code out.

You forgot the more likely reason: you probably have built a non-fully-functional copy of Qt. I bet it won't work on anyone's Raspberry Pi, including your friend's.

Comment: Thanks I will try that and the rigth command to install the library Is apt-get install qt5-default?

Comment: Thank a lots i don't know why but i use a another image and it's finally work.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is actually the **--platform** plugin you are using, linuxfb won't have any Windows borders because it's writing directly to the frame buffer, not to the X server. You need to use xcb.

And don't run it as root or you are likely to loose your DISPLAY environment.

Comment: How i can loose a display environment? I will try to run whit xcb.

Comment: if you run **su -** for example the DISPLAY __environment__ variable is lost, which defines to which X server the application should talk to.